# JPA find the Last entry

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I would like to know what's the best way to get the last entry of a table with JPA.
In Sql, what I'm looking for would be like:

```
select id from table order by id desc limit 1
```

I was thinking about model.count() but that sounds more like a hack than a good solution ;)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use a `JPQL query` that looks very similar to your query.

```
select t from JpaClass t order by t.id desc
```

After you establish your `Query object` you could then call

```
query.getSingleResult() or call query.setMaxResults(1)
```

followed by

```
query.getResultList()
```

EDIT:  My mistake:  Please note mtpettyp's comment below.

> Don't use query.getSingleResult() as an exception could be thrown if
>   there is not exactly one row returned - see java.sun.com/javaee/5/…()
>   - mtpettyp

Go with setMaxResults and getResultList.

```
query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
```

Comment: Don't use query.getSingleResult() as an exception could be thrown if there is not exactly one row returned - see http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()

Answer (score 70):

The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords **first** or **top**, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to top/first to specify the maximum result size to be returned. If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed.

```
JpaClass findFirstByOrderByIdDesc();
```

[referenced by Spring Data JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)

Comment: This approach seems to be easier than writing a custom query.

Answer (score 8):

I know I'm late to the party, but this might help someone.
If you want to fetch the latest entry by created timestamp. (When you don't want to rely on the table id):

`YourEntity findFirstByOrderByCreatedTsByDesc();`

Answer (score 1):

To the users that opted to use an entityManager, try this:

```
public List<T> findNRows(int n){
        return entityManager.createQuery("from "+entityClass.getSimpleName()+" ORDER BY id DESC",entityClass).setMaxResults(n).getResultList();
}
```