# Only last record from Custom query

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

The following query return a list but I am only interested in the last element of the list.

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationSeance.id=:seanceId AND r.seanceDate=:seanceDate")
public Reservation findReservationBySeanceDateAndSeanceId(@Param("seanceId") int seanceId, @Param("seanceDate") java.time.LocalDate seanceDate);
```

How shall I rewrite the SQL-Query in order to implement my idea?

Comment: The meaning of "last" is kind of blurred when there is no ordering defined in the query itself. Without it you are not guaranteed that the ordering is consistent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA find the Last entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061068/jpa-find-the-last-entry)

Comment: If i have list records i want get that have the biggest value of id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `ORDER BY r.id DESC` :

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Reservation r  " +
        "WHERE r.reservationSeance.id=:seanceId AND r.seanceDate=:seanceDate " +
        "ORDER BY r.id DESC")
public Reservation findReservationBySeanceDateAndSeanceId(
        @Param("seanceId") int seanceId,
        @Param("seanceDate") java.time.LocalDate seanceDate, Pageable pageable);
```

and because there are no way to use limit in JPQL, you can use `Pageable`

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 1);
Reservation reservation = r.findReservationBySeanceDateAndSeanceId(seanceId, seanceDate, pageable);
```

---

Another possible solution without Query :

```
public Reservation findTop1ByReservationSeanceAndSeanceDateOrderByIdDesc(
               ReservationSeanceEntity reservationSenace, 
               java.time.LocalDate seanceDate
)
```

In this second solution you have to pass the `ReservationSeance` Object and not the `id` of `ReservationSeance`, the query can be read as :

```
Find top 1 (first one) by `ReservationSeance` and `SeanceDate` order by `Id` Desc order
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, if you are using `mysql` as your database:

```
SELECT r 
FROM Reservation r 
WHERE r.reservationSeance.id=:seanceId 
  AND r.seanceDate=:seanceDate 
order by r.reservationSeance.id desc limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a couple more parameters to your query, especially an `ORDER BY` clause.

To get the latest `seanceId`, you'll want to order your results by that id, but in reverse order.  Then, just tell the query to return only the first result:

```
SELECT r FROM Reservation r 
WHERE r.reservationSeance.id=:seanceId 
AND r.seanceDate=:seanceDate 
ORDER BY seanceId 
DESC LIMIT 1;
```