# NativeQuery unknown column in field list

Tags: java, spring-data

```
@Query(value = "SELECT r FROM Reservation r WHERE r.reservationSeance.id=:seanceId " +
            "AND r.seanceDate=:seanceDate " +
            "order by r.id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
public Reservation findReservationBySeanceDateAndSeanceId(@Param("seanceId") int seanceId, @Param("seanceDate") java.time.LocalDate seanceDate);
```

Without nativeQuery as parameter I have error ',' or nulls expected, got LIMIT stackoverflow but when using it and set true i have error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'r' in 'field list'
```

EDIT: 
Entity used in query

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reservation")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalDate reservationDate;
    private java.time.LocalDate seanceDate;

    private Integer reservationNr;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Seance reservationSeance;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User userReservation;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Seance Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="seance")
@Data
public class Seance {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    private java.time.LocalTime displayTime;

    @ManyToOne
    private Film film;

    @Column(length=127)
    private String kind;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Hall hall;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reservationSeance")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

other day i hvae @JoinColumn buy in some days i delete this anotation

Comment: replace `r` by `*` or `r.*`

Comment: using * or r*  i have error com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'r.reservationSeance.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: I already answer your previous question to avoid all that https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018471/5558072 did you tried this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Reservation r WHERE **r.reservationSeanceId**=:seanceId " +
            "AND r.seanceDate=:seanceDate " +
            "order by r.id DESC LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
public Reservation findReservationBySeanceDateAndSeanceId(@Param("seanceId") int seanceId, @Param("seanceDate") java.time.LocalDate seanceDate);
```

I think this should be something like above.
The problem is happening, because you're trying use alias name **r** then field name **reservationSeance**, and then also field name **id**. It's not correct.

Please, provide your table to get more information about your issue.
I can suppose, that **r.reservationSeance.id** it's fk, and in this case, you should use full fk name, which was pointed in your `@JoinColumn name` annotation.

Updated.

Please, have a look at Reservation or Seance class, there will be relationship annotation. Where you used `@OneToMany` for example, then should be `@JoinColumn name = 'your_fk_name'`
And then, please, paste this fk_name to query instead of r.reservationSeance.id.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '**r.reservationSeanceId**=4 AND r.seanceDate='2018-08-30' order by r.id DESC LIM' at line 1

Comment: r.reservationSeance.id it's fk you have right suppose

Comment: I've added some changes to my answer. Look)

Comment: I don't use @JoinColumn in Reservation i have     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Seance reservationSeance;

Comment: Could you please provide your classes, which are using in this query?

Comment: Please, provide Seance class too, and I'm sure I will help you.

Comment: I add senace class

Comment: Okey, I got it. You should or get `@JoinColumn name='seance_id'` back, or look at table fk_name, and put it to query.

Comment: Thanks for attention